# Subview tabs doesnt show

Tags: tabs, ionic2

I have a tab navigation under the header on my subview, so i wrote the following html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>Productos</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top">
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Catalogo"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabTitle="Pedido"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-content padding>Foo !!</ion-content>
```

The navbar and the "Foo !!" are displayed but, not the tabs. Any ideas ?

Comment: is there a reason why you are using `ion-content` and `ion-tabs` in the same page? how do you expect it to show?

Comment: This is not how tabs should be used. Could you please tell us what are you trying to accomplish so we can see what would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. The ion-tabs must be have your own component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ProductCatalog } from './catalog.component';
import { ProductCart } from './cart.component';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})

export class ProductTabs {

    catalog:any = ProductCatalog;
    cart:any = ProductCart;

    constructor() {}
}


<!-- tabs.html only tabs widget -->
<ion-tabs tabsPlacement="top">
  <ion-tab [root]="catalog" tabTitle="CATALOGO"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="cart" tabTitle="CARRITO"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

ProductCatalog and ProductCart are two normal pages.